# How to prove the equivalent of minimum over minimum function using big-M method?

Tags: optimization, linear-transformations

I have a general minimum over minimum function as follows:

$(\textbf{P1}) \quad \min \{ \min \{  f_1(x), f_2(x), f_3(x)  \}   \} $

Based on the answer from [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858740/how-to-covert-min-min-problem-to-linear-programming-problem), we can simplify $z = \min \{  f_1(x), f_2(x), f_3(x)\}$, thus I have

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(\textbf{P2}) \quad \min \{ z  \} \quad  \text{s.t.} \quad
\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
z \geq f_1(x) - \mathcal{M} y_1, \\
z \geq f_2(x) - \mathcal{M} y_2, \\
z \geq f_3(x) - \mathcal{M} y_3, \\
y_1+y_2+y_3=2\\
y_1,y_2,y_3\in\{0,1\},
\end{array} \right.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $\mathcal{M}$ is a big-M method. However, I do not understand how to guarantee that $\mathbf{P1}$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{P2}$. Alternatively, how to proof that $\mathbf{P1}$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{P2}$? and is there any theoretical analysis of this linearization?

Comment: Think about what happens to the feasible region of $(x,z)$ when you enumerate the three different possible feasible choices of $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$.

Comment: Ask yourself what exactly you mean when you say P1 is equivalent to P2—that should make it easier to get started on a proof

Comment: @DavidM. I want to make sure that the result of P1 is the same as the one for P2. Since it is difficult to solve optimization P1 directly. Do you have a suggestion to start the proof?

Comment: I think the suggestion by madnessweasley is good. The proof might look something like “suppose $x$ is optimal for P1. Then there exists $z$ such that $(x,z)$ is feasible for P2 and produces the same objective value.” and vice versa.

Comment: @madnessweasley should I consider a case here? For example, when y1=0, y2=y3=1, then I decide the feasible region for each constraint? Is it sufficient to be a proof?

Comment: @bnbfreak Try to reason that for any $x$, the point $z = \min\{f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x)\}$ is feasible for (P2) by considering all three feasible triplets $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$. For instance, you can see that by setting $y_1 = 0$ (and $y_2 = y_3 = 1$), $z = f_1(x)$ is feasible for (P2)

Comment: @madnessweasley Please help me to check this quick proof. Suppose that $x^*$ is the optimal solution of $\mathbf{P1}$, and thus $z = f_1(x^*)$ if $f_1(x^*) < f_2(x^*)$ and $f_1(x^*) < f_3(x^*)$. Then, assume that $y_1 = 0$, $y_2 = y_3 = 1$, then from $\mathbf{P2}$, we get $\min\{z\}$ s.t. $z \geq f_1(x)$, then we can say that if $x^*$ is the optimal solution, $z = f_1(x^*)$. Thus $\mathbf{P1}$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{P2}$. What do you think?

Comment: @bnbfreak You are partly done. Even if you assume W.L.O.G. that $z = f_1(x^*)$, you have to show that the optimal objective value of (P2) is greater than or equal to $\min\{f_1(x^*),f_2(x^*),f_3(x^*)\}$ to establish that (P2) cannot attain a lower objective value (all you have shown so far is that the optimal objective value of (P2) is no more than $f_1(x^*)$). In theory, you also have to show that if $(x^*,z^*)$ is an optimal solution of (P2), then $x^*$ is also an optimal solution of (P1), but this is easy to show after you establish the above.