# Linearization of a Max-Max Function

Tags: linear-programming, linearization

I need help in the linearization of this maxmax function:

> max max {2x1+3x2, x1+4x2, 5x1+8x2} subject to: x ϵ X.

I already started it by:

α = max {2x1+3x2, x1+4x2, 5x1+8x2}

> max α
>
> α ≥2x1+3x2
>
> α ≥x1+4x2
> α ≥5x1+8x2

But I'm not sure on how to continue with the linearization. Thank you!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858740/how-to-covert-min-min-problem-to-linear-programming-problem/1862709#1862709

Comment: That question is for a min-min function. I see there must be an away of adapting it to maxmax but I don't see how.

Comment: @Kuifje my main question is that if it is possible to still use the Big-M constraints, since it is a maximization and not a minimization problem

Comment: it is possible ;)